# Vue 3 Page transition : how to have the next page already in place and reveal it with a swipe?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-transitions

I'm trying to make a page transition with vue router in Vue 3

[This image sums up what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiMz5.png)

I'm building a website with different pages (on the image: blue zone) that all have a scroll and a common fixed navigation bar at the top. If you click on one of the links of the topbar, it should move the entire page container to the bottom by 100vh to reveal a special view (on the image: red zone)

**My problem**

- As the yellow bar is fixed, I don't manage to make it leave with the blue page, it stays fixed at y:0
- I want to avoid clumsy stuff such as quickly adding on beforeRouteLeave a position:absolute top the navigation bar and compensating the top position based on scroll position.
- I don't really manage to make the 2 views be on top of each other, so that the blue page reveals the red page that is already in the right position.
- I don't manage to wrap my head around how I should approach this

**I've been trying different things for a few days:**

- Single <router-view> in App.vue that contains the blue views, and the red view. No luck.
- Two different <router-view> in App.vue. No luck.
- Various levels of wrapper with absolute, overflow hidden, given 100vh values, etc... No luck

**My questions**

- Would you know how I should split the different parts? (app, wrappers, sub-wrappers, croppers, ..)
- Can it be done with a single <router-view>?
- Can it be done without super clumsy JS on route change?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this idea can help you.

Since page is just a component that changed on redirect, you can create a page that contains both of your pages.
For example, according to your pictures, I'll have 2 pages (`Red` and `Blue`). Then, I'll create `Merge` that contains `Red` and `Blue`

This is `Red.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="red-page">
    Red page
    <div style="height: 200px" />
    <div class="link" @click="$emit('redirect')">To blue</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Red',
  emits: ['redirect'],
};
</script>

<style>
.red-page {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

.link {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

This is `Blue.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="blue-page">
    <div class="header" />
    <!-- Any content -->
    <div style="height: 700px" />
    <div class="link" @click="$emit('redirect')">To red</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Blue',
  emits: ['redirect'],
};
</script>

<style>
.blue-page {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 1000px;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 90vw;
}

.link {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

This is `Merge.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Red
      style="position: fixed; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; z-index: -9999"
      @redirect="redirect(false)"
    />
    <Transition name="slide-down">
      <Blue v-if="isBlue" @redirect="redirect(true)" />
    </Transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Blue from './Blue.vue';
import Red from './Red.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Merge',
  components: { Blue, Red },

  data: () => ({
    isBlue: true,
  }),

  methods: {
    redirect(toRed) {
      this.isBlue = !toRed;
      history.pushState({}, null, this.isBlue ? '/blue' : '/red');
    },
  },

  created() {
    this.isBlue = this.$route.path === '/blue';
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.slide-down-enter-active {
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
}

.slide-down-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
}

.slide-down-enter-from,
.slide-down-leave-to {
  transform: translateY(1000px);
}
</style>
```

Put both `Red` and `Blue` inside `Merge`. Then wrap `Blue` with `<Transition/>`. By this, you can add transition to `Blue` and make it slide down to reveal `Red`. Finally, inside `Red` and `Blue`, emit some signal when you try to redirect

The detail is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-fyebnk

In this example, I've made `Blue` slides down when go to `Red` and slides up when go back from `Red` to `Blue`.

In `Blue`, you can see `Red` is rendered when you look at `Blue` right side. But it up to you to modify it since loading `Red` first can be wasting if user is not gonna use it.

And of course, the transition can only occur if you click link inside `Blue` or `Red`. Any other redirect method will just immediately show `Blue` or `Red`

Beside, if library is a way to go. I think you should have a look at [RevealJS](https://revealjs.com) or [sli.dev](https://sli.dev)

Good luck to you

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer duckstery, it's very nice of you. 
I'll be trying this tomorrow. 

One thing I notice on your code is that if you scroll down inside blue, then click on "To red", the transition first scrolls up inside blue, and then reveals Red. My problem is that I'm going to have long pages with many elements. I'd need Blue's "visible part at the moment you click" to move (with the fixed yellow bar), instead of the full Blue.

Do you think that's possible technically if I take your route? Ideally without a bunch of JS to crop out the Blue part that's above..

Comment: If that is the case, I think this code is more suitable https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-vb2utm. `Blue` will still scroll top but it'll set top to `-window.scrollY`. Technically, it'll show your visible part but with scroll at top (`scrollY = 0`). Then `Red` will show up by expanding from 0 -> 100vh while `Blue` translate to y 100vh. This will help you move both the yellow bar and the visible part downward

Comment: Amazing! I managed to implement all this in my case, and it's working. As I have multiple routes inside the blue view it was a bit of a nightmare for me to keep the router working after history.pushState, but I managed to make it work with a popstate listener and conditions on history.pushState(). Thank you so much duckstery. If I had more than 15 reputation points I'd upvote, I marked your answer as accepted.